# Android NDK future extended support for C++

Tags: android, irc, android-ndk

Is there any info about the future of extending the safe C++ header list in the NDK (or maybe some hints to what might be safe to use) ? Or how soon we can expect the next NDK update? Also will there be any tutorials and documentation comming out for the NDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not aware of any announcements regarding future plans.

the samples are here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/1.6_r1/index.html#samples

and the NDK itself contains documentation in the form of .txt files in the docs/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in using C++ with the Android NDK you should check out the modified NDK by CrystaX. He has rebuilt the Android NDK so that it has full support for C++, including C++ Exceptions, RTTI (Run Time Type Identification) and the Standard C++ Library.

There aren't that many changes, in fact CrystaX offers a link to the complete patch file from his website.

Check it out at http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk-r4.php